# In android FOR LOOP NOT waiting for translateAnimation in it to complete

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, translate-animation

I'm trying to run a for loop with a `translateAnimation()` of an `imageview` in it. For every iteration, the `imageview` has to move `i*20` times in front(in a curve if possible). But the **for loop executes fully** and **doesn't wait** for each animation. So the **animation executes just once**(the last `ith` time) and not `i` times. Please help me!!!

`

```
for(int i=m;i<=y;i++) {
     int w=20*i
     TranslateAnimation translate = new TranslateAnimation(0,w,0,0);
     myAnimation1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     translate.setDuration(1000);
     translate.setFillAfter(false);
     myAnimation1.startAnimation(translate);
     myAnimation1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}'
```

Comment: You really need to understand event driven threaded operating systems.  The for loop will create the animations, and send events to the main thread (the UI thread).  As soon as the event is dispatched, the loop continues with the next iteration.  Since the thread is completely busy, it cannot update the UI until the loop is finished, and the last animation is displayed.  Instead, use another thread, perhaps using a `Runnable` with a timer. http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html

Comment: Animations do not run synchronously. They are scheduled on the main thread. I suggest you look at how to use `ViewPropertyAnimator` (by calling `view.animate()`) instead of the old animation classes. You can add listeners to the end of a property animation, so you can actually chain the animations; however, it would be better to run just _one_ animation that has the full duration and path you want.

Comment: Thankyou for the answers, but the for loop is still not waiting.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a animation listener?
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/Animator.AnimatorListener.html

Something like

```
public void startNextAnimation(int count) {
if (count != 0)
   //setup next animation
else
   //done
myAnimation1.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            startNextAnimation(countdown);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
```